# New command for spacing letters in microtype

Tags: macros, microtype, letterspacing

How can i make a *new command* that increases the space in between the letters. I do not want to use the already existing commands like `\textsc`, `\Large` or `\footnotesize`; and if it's possible I prefer a command with an argument ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[babel=true,tracking=true]{microtype}

\SetTracking{ encoding = *}{ 400 }

\begin{document}

\textls{this is a test}

\end{document}
```

---

Is it possible recreate this setting in `microtype` with the new command? `LetterSpace=40 WordSpace=2`

---

Look at my answer and tell me if the commnet are rigth please. Thanks. whith this configuration i have the default letter spacing in all text and command, so no influence on any part of the document right?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\newcommand{\textlsLarge}[1]{{\Large\textls[400]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\textlsLarge{this is a test} % new spacing command that use the space specified in newcommand (400)

{\Large this is a test} % no influence on the large command 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Anthing wrong with `microtype`s `\textls{<Some text>}`?

Comment: @lockstep no but i want different command that make different spacing. `LetterSpace=40` is equal to 400 in microtype? is possible to  set also `WordSpace=` in microtype?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting section 7 of the `microtype` manual:

> By default, each character will be spaced out by 100/1000em=0.1 em;
>   this amount may be altered in the optional argument to `\textls`,
>   using the `\SetTracking` command, or globally with the `letterspace`
>   package option, with decreasing significance in this order.

Based on `\textls`, you may define custom commands that letterspace to a smaller extent than the default setting, and also commands like `\textlsLarge`. Note that font size switching within paragraphs may lead to improper line spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\SetTracking[no ligatures = f]{encoding = *,shape = sc}{120}

\newcommand*{\textsomels}[1]{\textls[40]{#1}}

\newcommand{\textlsfootnotesize}[1]{{\footnotesize\textls[800]{#1}}}% Note additional group!

\newcommand{\textlsLarge}[1]{{\Large\textls[-100]{#1}}}% Note additional group!

\begin{document}

\textsc{this is a test}% uses letterspacing as specified in \SetTracking above (120)

\textls{this is a test}% uses default letterspacing of 100

\textsomels{this is a test} 

\textlsfootnotesize{this is a test}

\textlsLarge{this is a test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good ! how i can not influence the `\textsc` command but only the `\textls` command. For examples i have use the `\textsc` command in a part of document but i want in that case the default letter spacing... Thanks !

Comment: `\newcommand{\textlssc}[1]{\textls[120]{\textsc{#1}}}`

Comment: Wonderful examples above.