# Is there a way to get wider spacing between the letters?

Tags: letterspacing

I need to achieve something like this.
I think using \hspace between each letter is not the best way, is there an alternative solution?
[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/capital-letter-expanded-letter-space-kerning?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66494/new-command-for-spacing-letters-in-microtype?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442939/197451

Comment: It looks like you are asking about word spacing, not letter spacing…

Comment: Should the letterspacing apply *automatically* to all author names in the formatted bibliography? If so, please advise as to how you create the bibliography. By hand, or with a software tool, say, BibTeX or biblatex/biber?

Answer (score 6):

From the showed example can be concluded that you looking for `\so` command from the `soul` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\so{text} text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From Soul documentation (pp. 8):

> You can define own spacing macros or overwrite the original `\so` meaning using the macro `\sodef`:
>
> `\sodef<cmd>{font inter-letter-space}{inner space}{outer space}`
>
> The space dimension, all of which are mandatory, should be defined in terms `em` letting them grow or shrink with the respective fonts.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
foobar \textls{barfoo} 

foobar \so{barfoo}

\sodef\an{}{.1em}{0.2em plus0.2em}{0.5em plus.1em minus.1em}

foobar \an{barfoo}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: +1 for simplicity.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, compare the result and warnings of `\so{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}` using this answer with what you get using `\textls{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522109/194703). (I did not downvote this, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Guessing that your desired result is letter-spacing (or tracking) single words:

If you are already using `fontspec` or `microtype` in your code, those packages allow you to letterspace.

You can use microtype's letterspacing by using `\textls{your text}` around the part you want letterspaced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
foobar \textls{barfoo}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

You can adjust the amount of space between letters with the `letterspace` option. For example `\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you give a fully compilable code as well as a screenshot of its result?

Comment: @AndréC Hello. Added an example, although I fear that it won't help much as they haven't specified anything in the question, really. As has been pointed out by js bibra below the post, if the question really was about letter-spacing, then it has been answered multiple times before.